# Сохранение расположения колонок в Ext.grid.Panel при повторном создании компонента ExtJS 5

Tags: extjs

Кусок базового класса ..  поля таблицы определяются в классе потомка.
все прекрасно работает но только при первом создании компонента.
если повторно попробовать создать этот компонент (не перезагружая страницу браузера), то все настройки данного грида приходят в базовое состояние.
Перепробовал самостоятельно сохранять состояние грида ..но результат получался весьма странный .. 
Что то мне подсказывает что данная проблема решается куда проще .. может поделитесь своим богатым опытом ? Спасибо.

Ext.define('app.class.view.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    header: true,
    region: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    columnLines: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    title: 'Form1', 
    ...

```
stateEvents: ['columnresize', 'columnmove', 'show', 'hide'], //  which event 

initComponent: function() {
 me = this;     
 me.stateful = true;
 me.stateId = Ext.getClass(me).getName()+'grid';    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On a stateful grid, not only should the Grid have a stateId, each column of the grid should also be configured with a stateId which identifies that column locally within the grid.

Omitting the stateId config from the columns results in columns with generated internal ID's. The generated ID's are subject to change on each page load making it impossible for the state manager to restore the previous state of the columns.

из всего выше написанного понятно одно что stateId нужно прописывать для каждого столбца.. проверил вроде работает ...